# Combine code with view controller in Storyboard via instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I'm learning Objective-C, and ran into something which doesn't make sense to me.

When we have a view controller (VC) drawn in Storyboard, you can call this VC via code by entering a string into the Storyboard ID (click on the VC in Storyboard, in Utilities sidebar, Identity Inspector tab, Identity section) using the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method.

In my example, I've drawn a standalone UIViewController in Storyboard and set Storyboard ID to "orderList".  In the code, I can call this view by this code, **Code1**:

```
UIViewController *ordersVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"orderList"];
```

If I create a subclass of UIViewController called "SCVCOrders", and insert some code into it that modifies how it looks - like setting a title or changing the background color I thought I'd be able to use this code **Code2** to combine the drawn VC with the code in SCVCOrders:

```
SCVCOrders *ordersVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"orderList"];
```

But it doesn't combine them.  It only uses what is drawn in the Storyboard.  So next, in Storyboard, I set the drawn VC's class to SCVCOrders.  Now **Code2** gives me the combined look, but so does **Code1**.  My conclusion from this is that Storyboard is taking precedence over the instantiation code.  Xcode doesn't care what class I code the view to be, it will just look at Storyboard for this.  Is this correct?

I imagine it would be useful to have ability to layer my code on top of what I draw in Storyboard.  Using my example, I'd like to leave my drawn VC as the generic class.  And use **Code2** to layer code on top of the drawn VC.  Or how else can we achieve something like this?

Comment: actually there is no semantic difference between Code1 and Code2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will return whatever class is stored in the storyboard.  Storing the class returned by this method in a pointer with a different class type doesn't change what kind of object that it actually is.

Ie, if you have a fish and call it a tiger, it doesn't change the fact that it is really a fish.